# MS Access transfer text throws unparseable errors when quotes and apostrophes are together

Tags: ms-access, macros

A section of what I'm parsing is this

```
E,"1"".""0""1","1""/""1""1","3""4""5""6","6""5""4""3",'1"'1"'1"'1","1""1""/"
```

The parse always stops at '1"'1"'1"'1" right on the first quotation. Nothing after that is put into the table

Its being imported using the transfer text macro from a txt file. I have tried using both text and memo types for the specification and it's still failing. Is there a work around to this?

Edit: Yay setting the text qualifier to none fixes it!

Comment: Just to confirm: Is this "parsing" taking place as part of a CSV Import?

Comment: Okay, so what are you doing with the text file that is causing it to be parsed?

Comment: importing it with transfertext

Answer (score 1):

Splitting up your input string into what I believe you think the fields should be:

`E`,`"1"".""0""1"`,`"1""/""1""1"`,`"3""4""5""6"`,`"6""5""4""3"`,`'1"'1"'1"'1"`,`"1""1""/"`

Even if the second-last field is not impossible to parse (heck, *I* did it and I'm not really all that clever...), I'm not surprised that Access chokes in it. In my experience with Microsoft Office apps and CSV files the rule is:

> Text fields need to be enclosed in double-quotes if they contain commas or double quotes.

So, one might expect `1,O'Rourke,2` to pass, or maybe even `1,'thing,2`, but `1,'abc"xyz,2`? Not likely.

The workaround would be to fix the input file, e.g., by running it through a pre-processor to fix up the quoting.

Comment: @gta0004 I was typing the "workaround" part when you commented.

Comment: oh alright. thanks, but setting the text qualifier to none fixed it for me